# How to use Xcode output to determine source of crash?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, crash-dumps

I have the following output from my app at the moment:

```
2012-09-14 11:55:32.558 projectname[2172:707] -[__NSCFBoolean isEqualToString:]:
  unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3ec4ba18
2012-09-14 11:55:32.570 projectname[2172:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught 
  exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFBoolean isEqualToString:]: 
  unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3ec4ba18'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3263788f 0x3468d259 0x3263aa9b 0x32639915 0x32594650 0x41e47 0x417d3 0x46af7 
  0x320beefb 0x320bdfd9 0x320bd763 0x32061f15 0x325961fb 0x342faaa5 0x342fa6bd 
  0x342fe843 0x342fe57f 0x342f64b9 0x3260bb1b 0x32609d57 0x3260a0b1 0x3258d4a5 
  0x3258d36d 0x316e4439 0x3208ccd5 0x17e77 0x15ca4)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

I can see that the problem is that I'm trying to compare a `BOOL` to an `NSString`, the comparison is on data from a web service and it's always been `BOOL` before now. That's besides the point in this case anyway.

What information is in that log that can actually help me find the line of code that's causing the problem? I can see which instances (e.g. `0x3ec4ba18`) are causing it but the log doesn't even tell me what type they are, let alone a line number.

Comment: If the debugger is still active at the moment of the crash, you can try the following in the prompt `po 0x3ec4ba18` (po = print object). You might be able to figure out which object caused the crash like this. An alternative might be `info symbol 0x3ec4ba18`. More info here: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/debugging-tips-for-objective-c.html

Comment: This is the output I get: `(lldb) po 0x3ec4ba18\n
(int) $19 = 1053080088 0` (\n added)

Comment: I didn't even realise the `(lldb)` was an interactive prompt!

Comment: Sadly not very helpful information from the prompt. You'd have to use other debugging techniques I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Add an exception breakpoint by going to the exceptions pane (in the left sidebar), clicking the + and selection "Exception breakpoint". Then when you run the debugger will pause where the exception is actually thrown rather then when it is caught (or rather uncaught) at the top level.

Comment: This is now in the "Breakpoint Navigator" tab, in the left column of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

There are many tutorials on this, Raywinderlich has one of good tutorial for determining crash from the console log..
Here you can get them..

[My App Crashed, Now What? – Part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1)

[My App Crashed, Now What? – Part 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10505/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-2)

After following these, come to know the specific reason of crash then google for this, you can resolve it easily.